# Java program crashes with StackOverflow when using bubble sort of a large array

Tags: java, arrays, stack-overflow, bubble-sort

I have written a small Java program implementing the bubble sort technique for int arrays. It works for arrays of 1000 units, but when I increase it to 10 000, it crashes with java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class BubbleSort
{
  public static void main (String [] argv)
  {
    int Array [] = new int [10000];
    for (int a = 0; a < 10001; a++)
    {
    Array[a] = (int) (Math.random()*100);
    }  
    // generated an array of 10000 units and filled with random numbers

    for (int end = Array.length-1; end >= 0; end--)
    {
      BubbleSort (Array, 0, end);
    }

  }


  public static int BubbleSort (int A [], int count, int end)
  {

    if (count == end) //debugger says crash occurs here
    {
      return count;
    }

    else
    {

       if (A[count] > A[count+1])
       {
         int temp = A[count];
         A[count] = A[count+1];
         A[count+1] = temp;

         return BubbleSort(A, count+1, end); //and here

       }

     else
     {
        return BubbleSort(A, count+1, end);
     }
  } 

 }
}
```

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using recursion? Are you sure `a < 10001` looks like it would crash first? Please follow Java capitalization conventions.

Comment: Beware using recursion in Java: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/194646/what-methods-are-there-to-avoid-a-stack-overflow-in-a-recursive-algorithm

Comment: @ecbrodie The mere existence of stack overflows and/or the lack of tail recursion optimization isn't a reason to avoid recursion in Java or any other language.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Typo, sorry, it was meant to be a<10000;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping aside the logic, the technical reason as to why it fails at `10000` is because each thread in Java has a *fixed stack size*. And when you use 10000 it is unable to find enough memory.

Use `-XX:ThreadStackSize=512` to increase the default memory that JVM allocates to threads and it may work. But generally you don't have to bother about it.

On a sidenote check whether you really require recursion over here.

Comment: If I don't use recursion (as you rightfully noted, I don't need it, but I wanted to practice doing them), I won't need to increase the fixed stack size?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It is enough for normal applications. Only when you have some special requirements like this, change is required.